# is there any way to set repirt path by pasdinf through csv file?

Tags: jmeter

Am reading the report from CSV file that what I want to keep my report file, in the view result tree I passed as `${rootpath}` but it is not creating any report file in the specified path.

```
Path...c:\\project\report
```

How will take this kind variable to store the result?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the way is ${root_path}\JmeterReportTest.csv

${root_path} value reading from csv file.

reading path from csv is "c:\project" but not seeing any report csv file in the path.

if i am wrong then please let me know

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Path is incorrect, Correct path: c:\project\report.csv

You can either use file extension as ".csv" or ".jtl"

hope this will help.